# CentOS 7 add new user with root privileges

Tags: ssh, centos, terminal, sshd

I am reading [this tutorial](http://www.servermom.org/basic-centos-setup-before-building-a-working-server/414/), and trying to create a new user with root privileges and then block root access via ssh in a CentOS 7 server.  The problem is that the new user is blocked from doing root actions like `nano /etc/sudoers`.  Also, I seem unable to remove the block of root login.  So my pre-existing open root session is the only access I have to root functionality until it terminates.  **How can I successfully add root permissions to the newuser?  And how can I successfully turn on/off root login?**

Here is what I have so far:

In `/etc/sudoers`, I have:

```
## Allow root to run any commands anywhere
root    ALL=(ALL)   ALL
newusername  ALL=(ALL)  ALL
```

Note that I edited `/etc/sudoers` because `/usr/sbin/visudo` did not work.

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have `PermitRootLogin yes` because I want to turn root login back on until I can get newusername to have root privileges. Also, the last line of the file is `AllowUsers newusername`.

I then typed `systemctl reload sshd.service` because `/etc/init.d/sshd reload` threw an error on `CentOS 7`.

The problem is that currently `newusername` does not have `root` privileges and yet I am not able to login as `root` either.  So my pre-existing connection as `root` is my only way of controlling the machine.

**EDIT #1**

I was able to give the new user `sudo` privileges with `gpasswd -a newusername wheel`, but I still cannot log in as root even though I have `PermitRootLogin yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.  **How can I get `CentOS 7` to respect the settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?** I should be able to turn root login on and then off again at will, and have the settings actually work.

Comment: Anytime you change the contents of sshd_config you will need to either reboot your system or restart the sshd daemon.

Comment: @mdpc the server is on a remote network.  i am logging into it via `ssh`.  Do I have to get someone at the physical location of the server to restart the `sshd daemon`?  I am concerned that running `systemctl stop/start sshd.service` remotely via `ssh` would cause my connection to close after the `stop` and before the `start`, thus locking me out.

Comment: For that matter, `/etc/sudoers`should not be edited unless using `visudo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am reading this tutorial, and trying to create a new user with root privileges and then block root access via ssh in a CentOS 7 server. The problem is that the new user is blocked from doing root actions like nano /etc/sudoers. Also, I seem unable to remove the block of root login. So my pre-existing open root session is the only access I have to root functionality until it terminates. How can I successfully add root permissions to the newuser? And how can I successfully turn on/off root login?

1. Strictly speaking, the real use of `sudo` is to configure the execution of certain specific commands to certain specific users or groups. The way `sudo` is distributed and configured  in some distributions can be somewhat misleading because to become the root user, we can just type `su -` without involving `sudo`. This requires the entry of the password for the user, *root*, and **not** the user's password. So you could have used this.
2. Try to never use anything except `visudo` to directly edit `/etc/sudoers`. Otherwise you could break authentication altogether until you change its permissions back to `0400` (which you cannot do after you log out without utilizing a rescue system of some sort). (The editor used by `visudo` can be controlled by the `VISUAL` environment variable. To use it with `nano`, one option is `VISUAL=nano visudo`.)
3. The new user already can become root (point 1), but to let this user become root though sudo, just add the user to the right group. On CentOS 7, the traditional group name of *wheel* was used to allow members of that group to become *root* via sudo: `usermod -a -G wheel codemedic`. Use `man usermod` for more details. You can determine this group name by reading the configuration file: `cat /etc/sudoers`.
4. To deny access to *root* via SSH, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and make sure that only one uncommented instance of `PermitRootLogin` is available and set it to a value of *no*: `PermitRootLogin no`. Save the file and restart the Secure Shell daemon: `systemctl restart sshd`.

> Note that I edited /etc/sudoers because /usr/sbin/visudo did not work.

How does `visudo` not work?

Comment: Thank you and +1 for taking the time to write an informative answer.

Answer (score 7):

The way CentoOS grants root(all) privileges to a user is by putting them in the `wheel` group. This is what happens when you make a user account and select the box that makes that user an Administrator.

You can put a user in a group with:

`sudo usermod -aG wheel username`

To disable an account from logging in, including the `root` account
you can lock it by setting a non usable password.

`sudo passwd -l username`

Comment: Your response is similar to the `gpasswd -a newusername wheel` in the 2014 edit to the OP above.  Technically, `sudo` only lets users do some `root` operations.  There are still certain commands which a `sudoer` cannot execute unless they `su -` to actually become root.  I think a good answer would describe how to create the `someuser` account privileges that would enable them to perform **any** command if another user elevates to that account via `su - someuser`.  But I am giving this +1 because you took the time to respond to an old posting.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

These steps worked for me.

Add user:

```
useradd user
```

Add password:

```
passwd user
```

Add following line to the `/etc/sudoers` file by using the command `visudo`:

```
user ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

or, for becoming root without having to enter a password,

```
ALL ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Then, switch to that user

```
su user
```

and ask for root privileges:

```
sudo su -
```

Enter password for new user:

```
[sudo] password for user:
```